# Queues in validation rule not working

Tags: validation-rule, queue

How to exclude queues from validation rules in salesforce ?

I have custom validation rule where I need to turn it off for the queue name 'Sales'

Below is my code : `IF( ( ISPICKVAL(Status,'Closed') || ISPICKVAL(Status,'Not Active') ) && ( Reason_For_Closing_Case__c = Null ) , true , false )`

Any help is much appreciated!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
IF( ( ISPICKVAL(Status,'Closed') || ISPICKVAL(Status,'Not Active') ) 
&& ( Reason_For_Closing_Case__c = Null ) 
&& (Owner:Queue.QueueName!='Sales') , true , false )
```

You can access the queue name using "Owner:Queue.QueueName". If its a normal user, this condition will always be true (Queue comparison condition)